# Editing One Actors Gravity In PhysX

Tags: c++, physx

So, right now, I'm trying to work on a Helicopter system for a game. The issue i'm having it, I want to edit the gravity for the helicopter, and only when I'm in / using it, but right now it's causing all objects that use PhysX to lose it's gravity.

Here's the function I'm using. The `g_pPhysicsWorld->PhysXScene->setGravity(HeliGravity);` is what may be causing the problem.

```
  void obj_Vehicle::HelicopterPhysx() // controls of helicopter
{
    if (isHelicopter == true)
    {
        const float fTimePassed = r3dGetFrameTime();
        PxTransform pose = vd->vehicle->getRigidDynamicActor()->getGlobalPose();
        r3dVector angles;
        r3dPoint3D position(0,0,0);
        PxVec3 HeliGravity(0,0,0);

        if (HasDriver() && HSpeed > 70)
        {
            if (Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsRight)) // Rotate Left
            {
                if (!(Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsW) || Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsS)))
                    HelyX+=0.5f;
            }
            else if (Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsLeft)) // rotate Right
            {
                if (!(Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsW) || Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsS)))
                    HelyX-=0.5f;
            }
            if (Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsW) && distanceFromGround>=5) // move front
            {
                HeliGravity = PxVec3(0,-1.0,0);
                if (HelyY<15.0f)
                    HelyY+=0.5f;
                //HelyUp=-0.1f;

                if (HelyFB>1 && FB>=0)
                    FB=HelyFB-=0.25f;
            }
            else {
                if (FB >0 && HelyFB<20)
                    FB=HelyFB+=0.05f;

                if (HelyY>0)
                {
                    HelyY-=0.5f;
                    if (HelyY<0) HelyY = 0;
                }
            }
            if (Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsS) && distanceFromGround>=5) // Move back
            {   
                if (HelyY>-15.0f)
                    HelyY-=0.5f;

                if (HelyFB>5 && FB<=0)
                    FB=abs(HelyFB-=0.5f)*-1;
            }
            else {
                if (FB <0 && HelyFB<20)
                    FB=abs(HelyFB+=0.05f)*-1;
                if (HelyY<0)
                {
                    HelyY+=0.5f;
                }
            }
            if (Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsD) && distanceFromGround>=10) // move Right
            {
                if (HelyZ>-30.0)
                    HelyZ-=0.5f;

                if ((Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsW) || Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsS)))
                {
                    HelyX+=0.5f;
                }
                else {
                    if (HelyLR>5 && LR>=0)
                        LR=HelyLR-=0.5f;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (LR >0 && HelyLR<20)
                    LR=HelyLR+=0.1f;
                if (HelyZ<0)
                {
                    HelyZ+=0.5f;
                }
            }

            if (Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsA) && distanceFromGround>=10) // move Left
            {

                if (HelyZ<30.0)
                    HelyZ+=0.5f;

                if ((Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsW) || Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsS)))
                {
                    HelyX-=0.5f;
                }
                else {
                    if (HelyLR>5 && LR<=0)
                        LR=abs(HelyLR-=0.5f)*-1;
                }

            }
            else {
                if (LR <0 && HelyLR<20)
                    LR=abs(HelyLR+=0.1f)*-1;

                if (HelyZ>0)
                {
                    HelyZ-=0.5f;
                    if (HelyZ<0) HelyZ = 0;
                }
            }
            if (Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsQ) && HSpeed > 70) // move up
            {
                //r3dOutToLog("###### distanceFromGround %f\n",distanceFromGround);
                //if (distanceFromGround<100)
                    //HelyUp=0.1f;
                HeliGravity = PxVec3(0,2,0); //m70b1jr gravity
            }
            else if (Keyboard->IsPressed(kbsZ)) // Move down
            {
                HeliGravity = PxVec3(0,-1,0);
                //HelyUp=-0.1f;
            }
        }
        else {

            if (distanceFromGround>0)
            {
                if (HSpeed < 50 || !CheckFuel())
                {
                    //r3dOutToLog("######## HSpeed: %f\n",HSpeed);
                    //Gravity = PxVec3(0,-9.81f,0);
                    if (HelyUp>0)
                        HelyUp=-0.1f;
                }
            }
        }
        pose.p.y+=HelyUp;
        if (HelyFB>=20)
            FB=0;
        if (HelyLR>=20)
            LR=0;
        //r3dOutToLog("######## HelyFB: %f FB: %f\n",HelyFB,FB);
        position = r3dPoint3D(pose.p.x,pose.p.y,pose.p.z) + (GetvForw() / FB) + (GetvRight() / LR);
                if (HelyUp<0)
                {
                    HelyUp+=0.001f;
                }
                else if (HelyUp>0)
                {
                    HelyUp-=0.001f;
                    if (HelyUp<0) HelyUp = 0;
                }

        //g_pPhysicsWorld->PhysXScene->setGravity(HeliGravity); // m70 test

        D3DXMATRIX RotateMatrix,RotateMatrix2,toOrigin,fromOrigin,boneTransform;
        D3DXMatrixTranslation(&toOrigin, -GetPosition().x, -GetPosition().y, -GetPosition().z);
        D3DXMatrixTranslation(&fromOrigin, pose.p.x, pose.p.y, pose.p.z);

        D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&RotateMatrix,R3D_DEG2RAD(HelyX),R3D_DEG2RAD(HelyY),R3D_DEG2RAD(HelyZ));
        D3DXMatrixMultiply(&boneTransform, &fromOrigin, &RotateMatrix);

        D3DXMatrixMultiply(&boneTransform, &boneTransform, &toOrigin);

        PxMat33 orientation(PxVec3(boneTransform._11, boneTransform._12, boneTransform._13),
                        PxVec3(boneTransform._21, boneTransform._22, boneTransform._23),
                        PxVec3(boneTransform._31, boneTransform._32, boneTransform._33));
        pose.q = PxQuat(orientation);

        /*D3DMATRIX m = GetRotationMatrix();*/
        pose.p.x=position.x;//HelyFB;
        pose.p.z=position.z;//HelyLR;

        /*HelyLR=position.z;
        HelyFB=position.x;*/
        vd->vehicle->getRigidDynamicActor()->setGlobalPose(pose);
        SetPosition(r3dPoint3D(position.x,pose.p.y,position.z)); //Another test
        r3dPoint3D vel = GetVelocity();
        vel.x *= pose.p.x;
        vel.y *= pose.p.y;
        vel.z *= pose.p.y;
        if(vel.Length() < 0.001f) vel = r3dPoint3D(0, 0, 0);
        SetVelocity(vel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setGravity()` is used to set global gravity of scene which affect all of its actors.

If you want "personal" gravity for an actor you have to disable global gravity for that actor:

```
PxActor::setActorFlag(PxActorFlag::eDISABLE_GRAVITY, false);
```

And then add your own force to the actor:

```
void PxRigidBody::addForce(const PxVec3& force, PxForceMode::Enum mode, bool autowake);
```

Note that `addForce()` must be called on each update frame.

Comment: When I do that, it makes my game crash.